# Connecting....Off the wall!

Tags: connect-wall

Here is another connect wall, made up of four categories of four words each:

```
board         hand         spire        case

cream         accolade     concrete     almond

cherry        earth        face         sugar

tile          pandora      crystal      gyoiko
```

The first to correctly identify each category will win the accept. Have fun!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - [cultivars of cherry](https://www.vcbf.ca/education/cherry-cultivars): gyoiko, pandora, accolade, spire
>  - dessert ingredients: sugar, cream, almond, cherry
>  - clock parts: hand, case, face, crystal
>  - floor materials: board, concrete, earth, tile

Comment: So close! rot13: V nz guvaxvat bs ubj gur ynfg sbhe ner hfrq va n svany cebqhpg

Comment: @jafe rot13(n jnyy?)

Comment: Or maybe (sybbe)?

Comment: @jafe: V xarj gung gur tlbvxb jbhyq tvir vg njnl, ohg V jnf ubcvat gung vg jbhyq gnxr n yvggyr ybatre. V nyfb gubhtug gung gur pybpx jbhyq or uneqre. Jnf vg gbb boivbhf? I'll have to create a tougher one...

Comment: @hat Gyoiko was definitely the starting point :) It's a big help to have some candidate which has only one conceivable category.