# A Tough Wall To Climb

Tags: connect-wall

[My first connect-wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/77615/50887) was too easy; here is a hard one, as promised.

There are four categories of five words each:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wetsuit | crystal | blue | lie |
| sink | wire | bear | aura |
| barcode | marker | swiss | LED |
| gate | syrian | airbag | hail |
| saga | relay | duck | IC |

Enjoy!

### Hints:

1. > Time to get innovative! (Maybe the clock will be your Bain?)
2. > You can replace "syrian" with "tulum"
3. > Wired in by now?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly?:

A

> Electronic components: ic (Integrated Circuit), led (Light Emitting Diode), gate, relay, wire, possibly crystal instead

B

> Actions: duck, lie, sink, possibly hail, bear, and relay

C

> Airlines: Blue, Swiss, Syrian, possibly Aura and Saga

Which leaves

> wetsuit, barcode, marker, airbag, and possibly hail, bear, relay, crystal, aura, and saga

Comment: You're so close for one of the categories, and you are on the right track for another...

Comment: See added hints.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: (I think)

> - Planes: Syrian, IC, Swiss, Airbag, Gate 
>  - Lights: Crystal, Led, Blue, Wire, Aura
> - Water: Wetsuit, Sink, Hail, Duck, Blue
> - Nouns: - Lie, Bear, Saga, Relay, Marker

Comment: I'm afraid they are all wide of the mark, sorry! By the way, "gaye" is "gate" in the puzzle.

Comment: I edited it... waiting for peer review

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I was hoping that you had some tricks I could could use; the old `<br>` works but it's by no means elegant...pity the formatting is poor when it comes to spoilers.

Comment: See added hints.

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

Group A

> Knives: Syrian, Swiss, [saga](https://www.lamnia.com/en/p/32118/knives/boker-saga-grenadill-knife-set), [IC](https://www.horwood.co.uk/items/food-prep/cutting-chopping/knives-1/judge-sabatier-ic-carving-knife.htm), bear

Group B (Partial)

> Rubber: wetsuit, duck, wire

Comment: @hat pls comment on my answer, thanks!

Comment: See added hints.